# What is the Infimum and Supremum of the Set $E= \{n/(n+1): n \in\mathbb N\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $$E = \left\{\frac{n}{n+1}: n \in\mathbb N\right\}.$$

I think that Infimum of this set exists and it is $1/2$ and the supremum of this set is $1$. But, I need a formal way to prove this that these are the infimum and supremum of this set along with that the fact that the values I have stated are actually the infimum and supremum of this set.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: This sequence is monotonic and convergent.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Comment: Assume that exists $a \in \mathbb N$ such that $\dfrac {a}{a+1} < \dfrac 1 2$. This means: $2a < a+1$.

Comment: What makes you think that the values are $1/2$ and $1$?

Comment: And for $n=0$ ?

Comment: Let me think, you use the convention $0\notin\mathbb N$, right?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $\dfrac{n}{n+1}= 1- \dfrac{1}{n+1}.$

Comment: Very nice hint Peter!

Comment: Gimusi, thank you, not so very, very difficult.:)))

Comment: Often simple facts are the most difficult to explain! You keep it easy!

Comment: Gimusi.Thanks. Simple minds with simple thoughts:))

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Note that

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(n+1)^2}{n(n+2)}=\frac{n^2+2n+1}{n^2+2n}=1+\frac{1}{n^2+2n}>1$$

thus $a_n$ is **strictly increasing**.